# CSS rotate transformation causes borders on chrome to mess up

Tags: css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome, css-transforms

I am using `font awesome 3.2`, `bootstrap 3`, and `jQuery dataTables`.

The following screenshots are the borders of a `thead`, and the refresh icon is hooked up to the `fnPreDraw` and `fnDraw` `Callback`s of the datatable.

Not Spinning:

[image: Not Spinning]

Spinning:

[image: Spinning]

So when I click on the refresh button, the data is refreshed, and during the refresh I add the class `icon-spin` to use `font awesome`'s spinning icon css transformation.

However, I've noticed that in `chrome` the borders of the `thead` and its cells are messed up when the css rotation takes place.  There are no issues with `IE` and `Firefox`.  What's causing this and how do I fix this?

Note: `Chrome Version 34.0.1847.132`

Comment: Did you ever come to the root of this problem?